# Can Restful web service contain functions

Tags: rest, distributed-computing

I am new to web-services. As I understood restful services is a method to achieve distributed computing. I know RMI  is also a method to achieve that along with many other technologies such as SOAP. Now my question is, I see so much admiration about restful web service in the internet. But as I know Restful only can contains states of objects. It can't contain functions. Is not it? Have I got it wrong? How could it be so strong then to achieve distributed computing. Why everyone say it is so better that RMI or SOAP then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. It doesn't contain function. Only holds the data.

The reason people say about RMI/SOAP about the function/operation are easy to manage just because you don't have to worry about the function/operation to execute. RMI is designed to invoke function in remote machine. And SOAP message having explicit operation and data which determine the function. Though RMI and SOAP are different.

But you can easily achieve this kind of functionality by using REST. **You are having only data for REST. And data can represent function/operation identity including the data for function/operation.** You just need to think about it. Though the tool/library for REST is vast to develop/maintain distributed services.

Answer (score 0):

The basis of Rest are resources - not to be confused with 'objects' - and verbs. A "resource" is anything that has a URI, and the "POST" verb is explicitely meant to be used to submit data to be processed, *without* defining what this "processing" consists in:

> The POST method requests that **the target resource process** the
> representation enclosed in the request **according to the resource's
> own specific semantics**

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3 (emphasis is mine)

The rfc also quite clearly states that a successful post doesn't have to result in the creation of a new resource:

> **If** one or more resources has been created on the origin server as a
> result of successfully processing a POST request (...)

Note the "if"...

IOW it's perfectly legal to have a resource whose goal is either to run some computation and return the result without creating any new resource (actually this should use a GET request FWIW, cf search engines etc) or launch some business process or whatever that will possibly change the application's state one way or another.

As to "why everyone say it is so better that RMI or SOAP", try to implement a SOAP service and a SOAP client by yourself and you'll find out that there's a *lot* of overhead implied that don't necessarily buy you much more than what you can do with a plain rest API.